# How to change the order of querying IP address (IPV4 or V6)

Tags: dns

In AIX, /etc/netsvc.conf file determines if IP6 address will be queried first or not. If "bind" is there then IP6 will be queried first. Is there any such file Linux or Solaris?

Comment: See `/etc/gai.conf` on Linux but your question is offtopic here.

Comment: On Solaris see `/etc/inet/ipaddrsel.conf` and the `ipaddrsel` command.